# Oracle - which bank holds most money based on the customers accounts

Tags: oracle

Trying to figure out which bank holds the most money..

```
SELECT *
FROM bank B
WHERE BSB IN (SELECT max(balance)
              FROM   registered R, Account A
              WHERE  R.BSB = B.BSB
              AND    A.accountNumber = R.accountNumber);
```

Comment: And the problem with the query is... ?

Comment: So... you're looking for a branch number (if that what your [BSB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_State_Branch) is) that happens to exctly match the highest account balance? Preumably that isn't what you meant, but that's what you've written. It's always useful to say what the problem is - if you get an error, or wrong results; and showing table structures, data, current result and expected result.

Comment: Sorry.. I will explain in more detail... I am looking to find the bank/branch that holds the most money combined based on the accounts that they hold. So I think there should also be a 'sum()' query that needs to be included. Cheers

Comment: FWIW, according to Wikipedia "BSB" is the Bank State Branch code in Australia. Don't know if that's how it's being used here, but I'll go with it... :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what the issues might be, as you haven't provided a statement of what's going on, but I agree with @AlexPoole that comparing `MAX(BALANCE)` to a `BSB` value (branch #?) probably isn't what you wanted to do. Perhaps the following will prove useful:

```
SELECT *
  FROM bank B
  WHERE BSB = (SELECT BSB
                 FROM (SELECT R.BSB, SUM(balance)
                         FROM registered R
                         INNER JOIN Account A
                           ON R.BSB = B.BSB AND
                              R.accountNumber = A.accountNumber
                         ORDER BY SUM(BALANCE) DESC)
                 WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
```

A slightly cleaner version, using a CTE (Common Table Expression) might be:

```
WITH BRANCH_BALANCES AS (SELECT R.BSB, SUM(balance) AS BRANCH_BALANCE
                           FROM BANK B
                           INNER JOIN registered R
                             ON R.BSB = B.BSB
                           INNER JOIN Account A
                             ON R.accountNumber = A.accountNumber)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT BSB, BRANCH_BALANCE
          FROM BRANCH_BALANCES
          ORDER BY BRANCH_BALANCE DESC)
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many fields are in the `bank` table there may be value in waiting until the last possible step to join to it and pull just the one record (I'm assuming there is a PK or at least and index on `Bank.BSB`).

```
with balances as (
  select
    r.BSB, sum (a.balance) as balance_total
  from
    registered r,
    account a
  where
    r.accountNumber = a.accountNumber
  group by r.BSB
),
ranked_balances as (
  select
    BSB, balance_total,
    row_number() over (order by balance_total desc) as rn
  from balances
)
select
  b.*
from
  bank b,
  ranked_balances ba
where
  b.BSB = ba.BSB and
  ba.rn = 1
```